# Material and Texture Changing Script (asked before)

Tags: python, textures, dropdown, maya

I am trying to create a script in Maya Python to change the material of a model through a dropdown menu and the texture of a model through a slider that will change the roughness parameters.  I am having toruble applying it to my model.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import maya.cmds as mc
if mc.window("ram", exists=True):
    mc.deleteUI(ram)

ram = mc.window("Material and Texture", t="Material and Texture", w=300, h=300)
mc.columnLayout(adj=True)
imagePath = mc.internalVar(upd=True) + "icons/scriptlogo.jpg"
mc.image(w=300, h=200, image=imagePath)

# A dropdown menu deisnged to change material/color of octopus
mc.optionMenu(label="Material",)
myBlinn = mc.menuItem(label="Red")
myBlinn = mc.menuItem(label="Blue")
myBlinn = mc.menuItem(label="Yellow")
myBlinn = mc.menuItem(label="Green")
myBlinn = mc.menuItem(label="Orange")
myBlinn = mc.menuItem(label="Purple")

# A slider designed to alter the intensity of the octopus' texture
mc.intSliderGrp(label="Texture", min=0, max=10, field=True)

# A button to apply any changes
mc.button(label="Apply" a="applyMaterial ()")

mc.showWindow(ram)

def applyMaterial():
   currentValue = mc.optionMenu("Material", query=True, value=True)
   if currentValue == "Red":
       mc.hyperShade(objects='lambert1')
       mc.hyperShade(assign='red')
   elif currentValue == "Blue":
       mc.hyperShade(objects='lambert1')
       mc.hyperShade(assign='blue')
   elif currentValue == "Yellow":
       mc.hyperShade(objects='lambert1')
       mc.hyperShade(assign='yellow')
   elif currentValue == "Green":
       mc.hyperShade(objects='lambert1')
       mc.hyperShade(assign='green')
   elif currentValue == "Orange":
       mc.hyperShade(objects='lambert1')
       mc.hyperShade(assign='orange')
   elif currentValue == "Purple":
       mc.hyperShade(objects='lambert1')
       mc.hyperShade(assign='purple')
```

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly the problems are which you have?

Comment: There are some parts of the code which can easily fail. Keep in mind that the title of a UI element is not the name of the element. e.g. creating a intSliderGroup(label="bla"), can maybe create a UI element called "bla" but it can be something completly different. The return value of the UI control command contains the real name: realName = intSliderGrp(title="bla"....), use this to query the contents. Have a look at the button command, the command is added with 'c=commandname', not 'a'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few problems.

1: Syntax error on your button. You forgot a comma.

2: The parameter 'a' doesn't exist for the button. Use `command` instead to run your function when it's clicked.

3: You need to assign a variable to your `optionMenu` in order to get its full name. You can pass this variable later when you want to query its current value. You should assign variables to the rest of your interface items.

4: There's no error checking. This will fail if lambert1 doesn't exist or any of your other materials don't exist. You could use `mc.objExists` to see if they're in the scene. If not, throw an error message to the user telling them to create it, or have your script create the material itself.

Provided the materials are in the scene, the following is working ok for me:

```
import maya.cmds as mc
if mc.window("ram", exists=True):
    mc.deleteUI(ram)

ram = mc.window("Material and Texture", t="Material and Texture", w=300, h=300)
mc.columnLayout(adj=True)
imagePath = mc.internalVar(upd=True) + "icons/scriptlogo.jpg"
mc.image(w=300, h=200, image=imagePath)

# A dropdown menu deisnged to change material/color of octopus
matOptionMenu = mc.optionMenu(label="Material") # Need to assign a variable here to capture its full name.
myBlinn = mc.menuItem(label="Red")
myBlinn = mc.menuItem(label="Blue")
myBlinn = mc.menuItem(label="Yellow")
myBlinn = mc.menuItem(label="Green")
myBlinn = mc.menuItem(label="Orange")
myBlinn = mc.menuItem(label="Purple")

# A slider designed to alter the intensity of the octopus' texture
mc.intSliderGrp(label="Texture", min=0, max=10, field=True)

# A button to apply any changes
mc.button(label="Apply", command="applyMaterial()") # Missing comma after label, and parameter needs to be command.

mc.showWindow(ram)

def applyMaterial():
   currentValue = mc.optionMenu(matOptionMenu, query=True, value=True) # Use the variable to get the value.
   if currentValue == "Red":
       mc.hyperShade(objects='lambert1')
       mc.hyperShade(assign='red')
   elif currentValue == "Blue":
       mc.hyperShade(objects='lambert1')
       mc.hyperShade(assign='blue')
   elif currentValue == "Yellow":
       mc.hyperShade(objects='lambert1')
       mc.hyperShade(assign='yellow')
   elif currentValue == "Green":
       mc.hyperShade(objects='lambert1')
       mc.hyperShade(assign='green')
   elif currentValue == "Orange":
       mc.hyperShade(objects='lambert1')
       mc.hyperShade(assign='orange')
   elif currentValue == "Purple":
       mc.hyperShade(objects='lambert1')
       mc.hyperShade(assign='purple')
```

Comment: You are a life savior!  Thank you so much!  Just one question, though: If I were to put in the mc.objExists command in the script, where would it go?

Comment: Probably right before your `mc.hyperShade`. You want to do the check before trying run on potentially non existing materials. If you found this answer solved your problem don't forget to mark it as accepted so everyone knows it's resolved.

Comment: I have this, but it keeps giving me # Error: No renderable object is selected for assignment #

Comment: if currentValue == "Red":
       mc.objExists, mc.hyperShade(objects='lambert1')
       mc.objExists, mc.hyperShade(assign='red')
   elif currentValue == "Blue":
       mc.objExists, mc.hyperShade(objects='lambert1')
       mc.objExists, mc.hyperShade(assign='blue')

Comment: My guess is that `mc.hyperShade(objects='lambert1')` is not returning any objects, so you're trying to assign a material on nothing. You don't need to include that line in every if statement since it's the same in every condition. You can save a few lines if you put it after currentValue.

Comment: There are still some problems in the script: The `mc.window("ram", exists=True)` will never succeed because there is no windows called "ram". In general you can never rely on the names of the UI objects you create becaue maya can rename it on demand. So the easiest strategy is to completely ignore any UI element names and only use the return values. If it is not possible, use a unique name and hope the best. In you code above, the window is named _"Material and Texture"_ what is an invalid because of the spaces and will be renamed to _"Material_and_Texture"_.

Comment: Completely agree. And the fact that Maya auto-renames to resolve naming conflicts makes this statement even more true.

Comment: Assigning shaders via the _hypershade_ command is not the best solution because it relies on selections. If you have a look at the scriptEditor what happens if you execute the commands, you will see that the _hypershade_ commands only call other commands. You should have a look at the 'sets' command. This is used to assign shading groups to geometry or create shading groups. This way you do not have to select anything but tell the command which objects you want to use.

Comment: Again I completely agree. Feel free to provide your own answer. I just fixed up the mistakes that was preventing the code from running so OP knows why it was failing.